# Как из переменной переданной в функцию использовать его значение?

Tags: python, pyqt5, peewee

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне использовать значение переменной? Работаю с ORM peewee, и при измененении, необходимо обновить значение в SQL базе. Это общая функция на несколько таблиц, с разными названиями столбцов. **active_column** как раз содержит названия столбца и это название надо прокинуть в update.

```
def update_row_tabl(self, row, column, text_cell, table_used, hat_name):
    active_column = list(hat_name)[column]
    table_used.update(active_column = text_cell).where(table_used.id == (row + 1)).execute()
```

Отрабатывает с ошибкой: **peewee.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error**

Comment: ну так проблема тут не с изспользованием переменной, а с тем, что где-то что-то синтаксически неправильно написано

Comment: могу предполагать, что `active_column` интерпретируется как имя столбца, а не параметр

Comment: вот пример из доки -> http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_examples.html#:~:text=res%20%3D%20(Facility%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.update(%7BFacility.initialoutlay%3A%2010000%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.where(Facility.name%20%3D%3D%20%27Tennis%20Court%202%27)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.execute())%0A%0A%23%20OR%3A%0Ares%20%3D%20(Facility%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.update(initialoutlay%3D10000)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.where(Facility.name%20%3D%3D%20%27Tennis%20Court%202%27)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.execute())

Comment: а что если так: `**{active_column: text_cell}` заместо `active_column = text_cell`

Comment: Спасибо! Именно это было необходимо: **{active_column: text_cell}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, Acinit! Это рабочий вариант: `**{active_column: text_cell}`